# Having Vertically Long display of Posts are good or not?

Tags: website-design, usability, recommendations

I have a fashion website **deemasfashion.com**, and the main webpage has a very long vertical display of content. My target market is Pakistani / Indians living outside of Pakistan or India.

My products are costly so I prefer the user to go to a single product page after landing on main page. There the user can read the full detail of product and ask question about that product (small input form there), and then the user can add to cart the product.

I am uncertain whether the page as currently designed would encourage that particular experience path, or whether there may be a usability problem with the very long content column. How would I go about doing a usability test for that?

(I am a newbie and appreciate the answers with links  or examples please. )

I have attached the screenshot [image: Website screen capture]

Comment: Hi Muhammad, have you done any usability testing of your site?

Comment: No @Erics i have not done any type of Usability testing. Please guide me how can test usability?

Comment: @JonW I dont know what is Usability, but i think it will work if no conflict with your rules :)

Comment: OK, it's been reopened. It could do with a few improvements here for formatting and grammar etc, but the community can sort that out for you. Thanks for making the changes.

Comment: @muhammadusman If you can edit your question to explain a little bit as to your desired goals for this page? Are you wanting users to quickly add one of the front-page outfits to their shopping cart, or to explore the categories first? Just describe what you imagine your ideal and happy first time visitor would do, and then we could recommend a suitable form of usability test you can use to verify if that actually happens (vs. you uncovering any ux issues).

Comment: Thanks @Erics My products are costly so i prefer user to go to single products page after landing on homepage. where user can read the detail of product and ask question about that product (small input form there). then user can add to cart the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ever going to work on one website, you might need to know:

- You can do some usability testing yourself even though you might not be a usability expert, because [anyone can do usability](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/anybody-can-do-usability/).
- A site with resources for [simple/guerilla usability testing](http://www.sensible.com/) will be enough to get you started; you shouldn't need too much detail.

Then, as you finegrain your work you can take it from there to the next step.

Comment: thanks @ekapros for your answer. i will be reading first then i will come back with new question.

Comment: Thanks  @Erics for improving, editing question and all the guidance. You have been really help full